# Why doesn't $(window).resize() work for me?

Tags: javascript, jquery, responsive-design

I'm working on a project and my goal is to make a video player with an embeded iframe be responsive when viewing on different screen sizes. I figure the best way to do it is using resize function. However, every time in the many different configurations I've tried to use the resize function it does not work. I expect the text to log to the console after every time the screen is resized, but instead it is not logged at all or only once when the screen is loaded and never again.

Why is this happening.

I know my jQuery is right because I log other things in different functions (like the width and height).

```
            window.onload = function() {
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    console.log(' <-GoT Here. You FOOL!');

                    var iframe = $('iframe');
                    var videoplayerW = iframe.width(); //640
                    var videoplayerH = $('iframe').height(); //150
                    console.log(videoplayerW, videoplayerH, ' <-This The width and height of iframe.'); //560 and 315


                    var ytplayer = $('#ytplayer');
                    console.log(ytplayer.width(), ytplayer.height(), ' <-This is the ytplayer demonsions'); //undefined

                    iframe.each(function(){
                        $(this)
                            .attr('style', this.height, this.width)
                            .removeAttr('height')
                            .removeAttr('width');
                    });

                    console.log(iframe.width());

                });

            }       

            $(document).ready(function(){
                $(window).resize(function(){
                    console.log('Should have a bunch of numbers');
                });
            });
```

Comment: `my goal is to make a video player with an embeded iframe be responsive when viewing on different screen sizes` You should use CSS media queries for this then, not JS

Comment: I tried to but the css for the embed is terrible coded. I know how to do it in css.

Comment: You don't need `$(document).ready` nested inside of `window.onload`. The document ready handler attaches to the [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) event which fires before `onload`.

Comment: @War10ck, thanks. I know that now